# ssh error: PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Tags: ssh

Suddenly I cannot access my server via `ssh` using my **ssh-key**. I can confirm that my ssh key is ok (tested with another server). For some reasons `ssh` asks user password, and even if I enter my password it says:

```
(~)$ ssh c0rp@c0rp.kz
c0rp@c0rp.kz's password: 
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

ssh stack on this error line until I press Ctrl+C.

The strange thing that I can pass command to execute via ssh, and it works:

```
(~)$ ssh c0rp@c0rp.kz "uptime"
c0rp@c0rp.kz's password: 
 08:58:29 up 181 days,  6:12,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
```

*I tried the same thing from two different independent computers, the problem is not on my ssh-client.*

I was tried to reboot server but it does not help.

Server is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

What can I do to recover ssh access to server?

Comment: i don't know exaclly what is the problem, but take a look at [this,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021641/how-to-fix-request-failed-on-channel-0) it may help.